# i want to save my proposals to local storage in javasScript

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

i am developing a opinion poll in JS, where user can create 1 request at a time. now i want to save the created proposals to the local storage,
so that everyone can see and it did not go away with page refresh. i know the designing is not great or the code but once i learn how to save it to local storage style will be improved

here is javascript code

```
    let button= document.getElementById('proposal').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    
    let req=`<textarea name="pro" id="req" cols="30" rows="10"placeholder='description'></textarea>
    <textarea name="pro" id="reqtime" cols="10" rows="5"placeholder='lastdate'></textarea>
    <textarea name="pro" id="reqdate" cols="10" rows="5"placeholder='minimum amount'></textarea>`

    let form= document.getElementById('request')
    form.innerHTML +=req;

})
    function createRequest(){
        let rdiv= document.getElementById('creq')
        let confirmation= document.getElementById('con').addEventListener('click',()=>{
            //console.log('hello')
           let oreq= document.getElementById('req').value
           let qreq= document.getElementById('reqtime').value
            let vreq= document.getElementById('reqdate').value

           rdiv.innerHTML="<h1>proposals </h1> <br></br>";
           rdiv.innerHTML+="Description:"+oreq +"<br></br>";
           
           rdiv.innerHTML+="Last date:"+qreq+"<br></br>";
           rdiv.innerHTML+="Minimum abount:"+vreq+"<br></br>";

           rdiv.innerHTML+=`Vote<br></br>`
           

           rdiv.innerHTML+=`<input id="yaha"value="0">`
            rdiv.innerHTML+=`<button id="ya">yes</button><br></br>`


           rdiv.innerHTML+=`<input id="yana"value="0">`
           rdiv.innerHTML+=`<button id="na">NO</button>`

           let input= document.getElementById('yaha')
           let inputn= document.getElementById('yana')

           

            document.getElementById('ya').addEventListener('click',()=>{
                input.value= parseInt(input.value)+1
            
            })
            
            document.getElementById('na').addEventListener('click',()=>{
                inputn.value= parseInt(inputn.value)+1
            })
           
        })
    }
   createRequest()
```

here is html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Dao</title>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
</head>
<body>
    <button type="submit" id="proposal">create proposal</button>
    <input type="button" value="confirm" id="con">
    <br></br>
    <div id="request"></div>
    <div id="creq"></div>
    
    

    <script src="dao.js"></script>
    
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Saving it to _local_ Storage will only enables the data to be kept alive on page reload. It won't make data available to anyone else.

Comment: i want to keep it like that.

Answer (score 0):

here is the code

```
function createRequest(){
    let rdiv= document.getElementById('creq')
    let confirmation= document.getElementById('con').addEventListener('click',()=>{
        //console.log('hello')
       let oreq= document.getElementById('req').value
       let qreq= document.getElementById('reqtime').value
        let vreq= document.getElementById('reqdate').value

       rdiv.innerHTML="<h1>proposals </h1> <br></br>";
       rdiv.innerHTML+="Description:"+oreq +"<br></br>";
       
       rdiv.innerHTML+="Last date:"+qreq+"<br></br>";
       rdiv.innerHTML+="Minimum abount:"+vreq+"<br></br>";

       rdiv.innerHTML+=`Vote<br></br>`
       

       rdiv.innerHTML+=`<input id="yaha"value="0">`
        rdiv.innerHTML+=`<button id="ya">yes</button><br></br>`


       rdiv.innerHTML+=`<input id="yana"value="0">`
       rdiv.innerHTML+=`<button id="na">NO</button>`

       let input= document.getElementById('yaha')
       let inputn= document.getElementById('yana')

     var json = {"reqtime":"qreq", "reqdate":"qreq"}; 
     localStorage.setItem('data', json);
     localStorage.getItem(json)

       

        document.getElementById('ya').addEventListener('click',()=>{
            input.value= parseInt(input.value)+1
        
        })
        
        document.getElementById('na').addEventListener('click',()=>{
            inputn.value= parseInt(inputn.value)+1
        })
       
    })
```

> 

```
 var json = {"reqtime":"qreq", "reqdate":"dreq"}; 
>     localStorage.setItem('data', json);
>     localStorage.getItem(json)
```

}

Comment: can u write the full code,?

Comment: But localstorage does the settings only for that user, it is used, for example, to select dark / light modes, it is only for that user, if he gave an anonymous mode, it would disappear, and the number in localstorage would not be stored.

Comment: If you mean this. localStorage.setItem('title', data)-YES. i want to save it.

Comment: Yes, but I'm saying that the user is left with no answer. As I looked down you have a vote, so you don't want everyone there to see max 1 of your vote, do you? Do you want to see all those voices there?

Comment: how to implement this localStorage.setItem('key', ...); then localstorage,getitem?

Comment: for example
localStorage.setItem('reqtime', qreq);

and for get localStorage.getItem('reqtime');

Comment: i want to save the entire proposals.not single entity.

Comment: Convert to json and save them

var json = {"reqtime":"qreq", "reqdate":"dreq"};
localStorage.setItem('data', json);

Comment: since i am not js dev so complete code will be helpful

Comment: ```var json = {"reqtime":"qreq", "reqdate":"dreq"};
localStorage.setItem('data', json);```

Comment: i put it inside the function, not working

Comment: Show code and error message from console.

Comment: nothing happening, its not getting saved

Comment: Show code and error message from console. I cant help you if i dont see code or error from console

(The cant be ""...)
{"reqtime": qreq, "reqdate": dreq}

Comment: take a look i just posted

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).